# Entity Framework query to get child items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have order structure as below

Order 1234

- Category 1

  - Item 111
  - Item 222
- Category 7

  - Item 444

How can I modify the query below to include all items from order 1234

```
public List<Items> GetAllOrderItems(int orderId)
{

   var result = (from o in _orderContext.Orders
                 where o.OrderId == orderId
                 select s).toList();
}
```

`List<Items>` => Item 111,Item 222, Item 444

Comment: Maybe a class definition of Order would help

Comment: Did you even try to Google this? There's dozens of answer already.

Comment: I think you need to select `s.Category` and then use `SelectMany` to get the items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SelectMany` for this. Here a simple example:

```
class Master
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>() { new Item(1), new Item(2) };
}
class Item
{
    public Item(int x)
    {
        this.X = x;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var masters = new List<Master>();
    masters.Add(new Master());
    masters.Add(new Master());

    List<int> xList = masters.Select(s => s.Items).SelectMany(s => s, (m, i) => i.X).ToList();

    foreach (int item in xList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```